# Passing parameters to navigator during creation

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm trying to pass a parameter down to all navigators from the root  component. It stops propagating at this point:

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
  }, {initialRouteName: "Main"})
);
```

Where I create the main navigator for the app. There is no props object to reference and copy parameters from since `createAppContainer` and `createSwitchNavigator` are both functions and the components that they create haven't been created yet.

Is there a way to do this?

For full context, i'm using AWS Amplify and trying to pass `authState` and `onStateChange` down to a sign out button that's far down the DOM tree.

Comment: which library navigation you using?

Comment: @YVG Did you got any solution. I am searching for a solution how to pass the params  in onStateChange. (Also, the error messages are retained in the login screen. Did you have any solution for that?